# Declaration of index in string.h overshadowed by cJSON.h

Tags: c++, string.h, cjson

I am trying to make a C++ program that makes use of the `string.h` and `cJSON` library. But when I build it, I get warning saying:

> cJSON.c:1743: warning: declaration of 'index' shadows a global declaration
> string.h:487: warning: shadowed declaration is here

These warning doesn't really affect the functionality of the program and the program runs as expected. But I am trying to build the program using AzDo pipelines for exporting it and the AzDo pipelines fails builds on warnings. So, I need to find a way to resolve these warnings. What can be the best way to resolve this?

Edit:
`cJSON.c` 1743 line is this:
`static cJSON* get_array_item(const cJSON *array, size_t index)`
`string.h` 487 line is this:
`extern char *index (__const char *__s, int __c)`

Comment: Don't use `<string.h>` in a C++ program is a good first step. Does it still happen if you use `<cstring>` instead?

Comment: @sweenish actually I am not directly using `string.h` some other library I am using has that include

Comment: Show those lines in the question.

Comment: @PeteBecker I added the lines

Comment: That's a really weird warning. It's saying that because there's an argument named `index` in the first line, that function won't be able to call the function named `index`. Of course, if that was, in fact, a problem, the implementor of `get_array_item` would have given that argument a different name. "Treat all warnings as errors" is a really bad policy because it causes this kind of problem. You might edit `cJSON.c` and change that name.